# tikz arrowhead type changes node positioning along curved path?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm trying to position a square node midway along a curved path, but I've noticed that the arrowhead style I select affects the positioning -- if I use an arrowhead other than the default, the node is positioned 'off center' in the normal direction to the path.  Is there a different way to specify this to have the node correctly centered with e.g. the 'latex' style arrowheads?

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[<->,bend angle=90,thick] (-1,-1)
  to[bend right] 
  node[rectangle,sloped,fill=black,minimum size=1mm,inner sep=0pt] {}
  (1,0);
  \begin{scope}[shift={(2,0)}]
    \draw[<->,>=stealth,bend angle=90,thick] (-1,-1) to[bend right] 
    node[rectangle,sloped,fill=black,minimum size=1mm,inner sep=0pt] {}
    (1,0);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(4,0)}]
    \draw[<->,>=latex,bend angle=90,thick] (-1,-1) to[bend right] 
    node[rectangle,sloped,fill=black,minimum size=1mm,inner sep=0pt] {}
    (1,0);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's not that the arrows are moving the node, but rather the different arrow types are redefining the path.

Comment: And, the node position appears to be calculated upon the path without arrows.

Comment: Arrowheads normally shorten a line by the length of the arrowhead, but that does not appear to be the case for curved lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be solved by using the TikZ `bending` library.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}

\tikzset{%
  my node/.style={rectangle,sloped,fill=black,minimum size=1mm,inner sep=0pt},
  draw my path/.style={draw,bend angle=90,thick,#1},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[draw my path={<->}] (-1,-1) to[bend right] node[my node] {} (1,0);

  \begin{scope}[shift={(2,0)}]
    \path[draw my path={<->,>=stealth}] (-1,-1) to[bend right] node[my node] {} (1,0);
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[shift={(4,0)}]
    \path[draw my path={<->,>=latex}] (-1,-1) to[bend right] node[my node] {} (1,0);
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It appears that the path used to calculate the node positions and the path used when drawing and adding arrows are different.  I've hobbled together the following to show the difference: red being the color of the path for the node.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{bending}

\tikzset{%
  my node/.style={rectangle,sloped,fill=black,minimum size=1mm,inner sep=0pt,#1},
  draw my path/.style={draw,bend angle=90,thick,#1},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[draw my path={<->}] (-1,-1) to[bend right] node[my node] {} (1,0);

  \begin{scope}[shift={(2,0)}]
    \path[orange,draw my path,thin]  (-1,-1) to[bend right] node[my node] {} (1,0);
    \path[draw my path={<->,>=stealth}] (-1,-1) to[bend right] node[my node] {} (1,0);
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[shift={(4,0)}]
    \path[orange,draw my path,thin]  (-1,-1) to[bend right] node[my node] {} (1,0);
    \path[draw my path={<->,>=latex}] (-1,-1) to[bend right] node[my node] {} (1,0);
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, that's a simple fix and solves the problem.  I'd still be interested if there is a way to access the original arrow path, though, as the arrows look a bit better without the 'bending' library IMO.